# ¿Ayuda con base de datos en Mariadb?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mariadb

Hola quiero insertar multiples productos, unidades, cantidades, fechas relacionadas por su misma orden de compra para despues poderlas mostrar dentro de una misma fila en una tabla, pero no encuentro como hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para ser mas claro que si tuvieran la misma orden de compra se juntaran dentro de la misma fila de a tabla, por cierto la cantidad de productos por orden de compra puede variar. Les dejo mis tablas:

```
 CREATE TABLE capturar_pedido (
        cliente varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        orden_de_compra varchar(255),
        producto varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        unidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        fecha_de_embarque Date NOT NULL,
        notas varchar(255),
        etiquetado char(2) NOT NULL,

        id_pedido BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido)
        )


        CREATE TABLE salida_materiales (


        folio varchar(255) NOT NULL,

        fecha Date NOT NULL,
        numero_remision varchar(255),
        numero_factura varchar(255),
        otro varchar(255),
        referencia_transporte varchar(255),
        placa_tractor varchar(255),
        placa_caja varchar(255),
        comentarios varchar(255),
        retorno char(2),
        fecha_posible Date NOT NULL,
        orden_de_compra varchar(255) not null UNIQUE,
        id_materiales BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_materiales),
        FOREIGN KEY(orden_de_compra) references capturar_pedido(orden_de_compra))


    CREATE TABLE coa (

    fecha Date NOT NULL,
    presentacion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    oc varchar(255),

    lote varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    produccion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    caducidad varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    sello varchar(255),
    apariencia varchar(255),
    resultado_apariencia varchar(255),
    sabor varchar(255),
    resultado_sabor varchar(255),
    olor varchar(255),
    resultado_olor varchar(255),
    color varchar(255),
    resultado_color varchar(255),
    pureza varchar(255),
    resultado_pureza varchar(255),
    humedad varchar(255),
    resultado_humedad varchar(255),
    id_pedido Bigint(10) not null UNIQUE,

    id_coa BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_coa),

    FOREIGN KEY(id_pedido) references capturar_pedido(id_pedido)


    )


    CREATE TABLE granulometria (

    parametro varchar(255),
    unidad varchar(255),
    especificacion varchar(255),
    resultado varchar(255),
    id_pedido int(10) not null,//hacerla foreign key pero no unica
    id_granulometria BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_granulometria)
    )
```

Comment: Lo único que entendí de tu pregunta es que quieres saber qué columnas usar para que tu tabla compras no tengas registros repetidos. Podría ser un índice único con las columnas `id_cliente` y `fecha_compra` siendo ésta última del tipo `DATETIME`. Es imposible que un mismo cliente registre dos compras en la misma fecha, hora, minuto y segundo. Las otras cosas que preguntas no las entiendo, explícate mejor, y si son muchas preguntas, mejor plantéalas por separado para que tu problema tenga una mejor recepción aquí. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano En si todo es parte del mismo problema no encuentro como insertar varios pedidos con la misma orden de compra de manera que pueda mostrarlos en una misma fila en una tabla haciendo un select, ya que en un mismo campo dentro de un registro no puedo insertar multiples productos, fechas(pueden ser distintas las fechas de entrega), cantidades etcetera, pero sigue siendo el mismo pedido

Comment: Por favor expón el problema con más claridad. Di exactamente como están constituidas todas las tablas, como se relacionan y da un ejemplo del resultado que quieres obtener.